# Show class dynamically based on parameter

Tags: html, css, angular

I have css classes that can have multiple names, how can I pass those names to an ngClass?

Example that doesn't work. How can I pass `itemName` to `ngClass`?

```
<div [ngClass]="isItem ? 'item {{itemName}}' : 'noItem {{itemName}}'">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not template interpolate inside `[ngClass]` directive just remove the brackets and concatenate the variable with string.

```
<div [ngClass]="isItem ? 'item '+itemName : 'noItem'+itemName"></div>
```